# How do I create a public game?

Tags: diablo-iii

I saw an option in Diablo-3 load screen to join public games. How can I create one of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've started a game, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to open the menu, and click the button marked "Open Game to Public"

[image]